# Split string by array of strings and preserve delimeters

Tags: c#, string

I have something like this:

```
  string[] names= {"john","joe", "jim"};
  data="john,4,3,6,joe,3,6,2,jim,3,6,7";
  string[] results=data.Split(names,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

this gives:

```
 ,4,3,6

 ,3,6,2

 ,3,6,7
```

but i want the names to be in the results array as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding this line at the end:

```
results = results.Select((x, i) => names[i] + x).ToArray();
```

This will prepend the name in front of each entry, outputting:

> john,4,3,6
>   joe,3,6,2
>   jim,3,6,7

Answer (score 3):

You could keep your original code, then zip in the names:

```
string[] names= new [] {"john","joe", "jim" };
string data="john,4,3,6,joe,3,6,2,jim,3,6,7";
string[] results = data.Split(names, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Zip(names, (values, name) => name + values)
                       .ToArray();
```